A polynomial with at least a simple root
Let $f\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ be a non-constant polynomial and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ be s.t. $b\not= 0$.
Then —I think so— (*) The equation, in $x\in\mathbb{C}$, $f(x)-a-ib=0$ admits at least one simple root.
For example, one can prove (using the Gröbner basis theory) that
$(x-a_1-ib_1)^2(x-a_2-ib_2)^2\cdots (x-a_6-ib_6)^2$,
where $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $b_i\ne 0$, is never in the form $f(x)-a-ib$.
Yet $f(x)-a-ib$ may have multiple roots:
$$x^3/3+x^2/2+x-(-5/12+i\sqrt{3}/4)=1/24(2x+1+2i\sqrt{3})(i\sqrt{3}-2x-1)^2.$$
Question. Is the above statement (*) true?

What is the question?

($a$ is unnecessary since you can replace $f$ with $f-a$)

($b$ is unnecessary since you can replace $f-a$ by $(f-a)/b$, hence $b=1$ is enough)

@YCor Jochen does not say that you can replace $b$ by $0$, but that you can replace $b$ by $1$.

@AlekseiKulikov I know, I erased it before you replied. Sorry.

You certainly need to assume that $f$ is not constant.

This question was asked and answered before: https://mathoverflow.net/q/81732

Yes. Let $g$ be a polynomial. If $g$ has no simple roots then the degree of $\gcd(g, g')$ is at least half the degree of $g$. (Each root of $g$ with multiplicity $m$ is a root of $\gcd(g, g')$ with multiplicity $m-1$ and $m-1 \geq m/2$ for $m\geq 2$.)
If $f(x)-a-bi$ has no simple roots then so does $f(x)-a+bi$. Both these polynomials have derivative $f'$ so $\gcd ( f-a -bi, f') \gcd(f-a+bi,f')$ has degree at least $\deg f$.
But $f-a-bi$ and $f-a+bi$ are coprime since their difference $2bi$ is invertible. It follows that $\gcd ( f-a -bi, f') \gcd(f-a+bi,f')=\gcd ( (f-a -bi)(f-a+bi),f') $ divides $f'$, hence (because $f$ is nonconstant and thus $f'\neq 0$) $f'$ has degree at least $\deg f$, a contradiction.

This is unexpectedly elegant!

Nice (note that the last gcd argument is incorrect if $f'=0$).

Biblical simplicity. Bravissimo.

The question was asked and answered before: https://mathoverflow.net/q/81732
